# How many times in a lifetime a man can do laser vision/eyesight correction/surgery?

Tags: eye, surgery, vision, ophthalmology, lasik

Is it true that laser vision/eyesight correction/surgery is strictly recommended to do only once in a lifetime and if after first laser correction someone's eyesight returned to bad condition the only option is to use glasses/lenses?

Comment: Which form of laser surgery?